# How to show default value jQuery radio button change event?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am a new developer. I have created change event function two radio button same name & id and different value.

I will call change event trigger, but default value related content not showing before radio button changes. How can I resolve that issue?

**HTML**

```
<td valign="top" width="37.5%">
<label><input type="radio" name="client_location_c" value="germany" checked="checked" id="client_location_c" accesskey="7" title="">Global Guide Services GmbH (Germany)</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="client_location_c" value="romania" id="client_location_c" accesskey="7" title="">Global Guide Services SRL (Romania)</label><br>
</td>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("input[name='client_location_c']").change(function() {
  var receipientData = "";
  if ($(this).val() == 'germany') {
    receipientData = locationBasedGermanyRecipient;
  } else if ($(this).val() == 'romania') {
    receipientData = locationBasedRomaniaRecipient;
  }
  autopopulateData(receipientData);
});

$("input[name='client_location_c']").trigger('change');
```

Comment: can you explain `default value related content not showing before radio button changes`

Comment: Do not use same id for two or more elements you can use same class name for these elements.

Comment: <label><input type="radio" name="client_location_c" value="germany" checked="checked" id="client_location_c" accesskey="7" title="" checked >Global Guide Services GmbH (Germany)</label><br>    use like this. Then first time default value is checked as Global Guide Services GmbH (Germany)

Answer (score 0):

`id` attribute should be unique, but whereas you can have `class` attribute

So better you use class,

```
$(".someclassname").change(function(){

}
```

Comment: OP is not using `id` for change event. So `id` is not causing any issue here. He want something else.